# CSS grandchild override overflow:hidden;?

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML structure (`parent` > `child` > `grandchild`), the parent has the `overflow:hidden;` property

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">        
        <div id="grandchild">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Can the `grandchild` element override the parent’s overflow hidden?

My main concern are that

- the grandchild's position is related to the child's position.
- since the child's position is related to the parent position, it has to move with the parent when scrolling.
- the grandchild's styles (`font-size`, `font-family`...) are inherited from the child.

The child must not be visible outside the parent, unlike the grandchild.

I already try many things. Nothing works and I start to wonder if what I want to do is possible.

In the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/qs0625Lr/13/), the blue box should be half visible, but the green one should be fully visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/qs0625Lr/13/

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to achieve here, but you might need a solution like this, https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: @CBroe Thx for the link. I'm working on, but it's hard to understand what makes the sub-menu popping out the top  `overflow:hidden` element

Comment: Removing the `position: relative` from the parent LI, in this instance. _"Basically, in order for an absolutely positioned element to appear outside of an element with overflow: hidden, its closest positioned ancestor must also be an ancestor of the element with overflow: hidden."_

Comment: @CBroe According to your last citation, what I want to do is impossible. The child's position is transformed with a translation. The closest positioned ancestor of the grand child is necessary the child which is not an ancestor of the element with `overflow: hidden`. I reproduce it here : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/ezyshn6c/ It works until you remove the commented line with the transform: translateX, which, I guess act as a `position: absolute` or `related`

Comment: That's why that solution uses JavaScript to add a wrapper, and then _calculates_ what position needs to be set for that wrapper. If something similar will work with your translate, you'd have to try and see.

Comment: @CBroe I added a wrapper, but the grandchild can't still go out the parent : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/ezyshn6c/3/ Did I miss something?

Comment: The fact that the transform is creating a new stacking context is probably interfering.

Answer (score 1):

If sizes and offsets of the elements are known, can be used `clip-path` instead `overflow: hidden`.
In the example below, entered something into css variables.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#parent {
  --child-width: 60px;
  --grandchild-translate-x: 100px;
  --bottom: -20px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% 100%,
    calc(var(--child-width) + var(--grandchild-translate-x)) 100%,
    calc(var(--child-width) + var(--grandchild-translate-x)) calc(100% - var(--bottom)),
    var(--grandchild-translate-x) calc(100% - var(--bottom)),
    var(--grandchild-translate-x) 100%,
    0 100%
   );
}

/* Must not be visible outside the parent */
#child {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: var(--child-width);
  height: var(--child-width);
  margin-bottom: var(--bottom);
}

/* Must be visible outside the parent */
#grandchild {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: var(--child-width);
  height: var(--child-width);
  transform: translateX(var(--grandchild-translate-x));
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">        
        <div id="grandchild">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Or generate a `clip-path` using javascript, if each element is responsive:

```js
clip();
$(window).on('resize', clip)

function clip(){
    const grandchild = $('#grandchild');
    const right = grandchild.position().left + grandchild.width();
    const bottom = grandchild.position().top + grandchild.height();
    const left = grandchild.position().left;
    const clipPath = `polygon(
    0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% 100%,
    ${right}px 100%,
    ${right}px ${bottom}px,
    ${left}px ${bottom}px,
    ${left}px 100%,
    0 100%
   )`;
    $('#parent').css('clip-path', clipPath);
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);   
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}

/* Must not be visible outside the parent */
#child {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}


/* Must be visible outside the parent */
#grandchild {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: translate(100px, 40px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">        
      <div id="grandchild">
      </div>  
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, but of course, each element  is responsive :/

Comment: Oк. Then you can generate a clip-path using javascript. Added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** `The only drawback is that it does not solution does not support scrolling`

In this update, we added a container to hold the children. We transform that container to the bottom of the parent, instead of using `#child` as the container. This snippet allows you to use your original code of transforms instead of using `bottom`.

```css
body {
height: 1000px;
}

* {
    margin:0;
}

#parent {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);   
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(60px);
}

/* Must not be visible outside the parent */
#child {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.4;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
}


/* Must be visible outside the parent */
#grandchild {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="child">        
        <div id="grandchild">
        </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fixed code not scrolling

With your current code, it does not seem possible. But if you changed your `#child`'s code from `transform: translateY(60px);` to `bottom: -60px` and your `#grandchild` to `position: fixed`, the code functions as you intended.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
}

#parent {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);   
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Must not be visible outside the parent */
#child {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.4;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
  bottom: -60px;
}


/* Must be visible outside the parent */
#grandchild {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    transform: translateX(100px);
    
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">        
        <div id="grandchild">
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The only drawback is that it does not solution does not support scrolling

Comment: The child's position is no longer related to the parent's position. https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/qs0625Lr/10/

Comment: @Fifi check out the updated code. This should solve all problems. Consider accepting this answer if so!

Comment: The new solution does not work. The child has a height of 40px, If you set it to 60px, it goes outside the red rectangle : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/qs0625Lr/12/

Comment: A fixed position will definitely not be adaptive...